# How do I delete a package from Windows Dev Center (Windows Store)

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have an x86 and an ARM version of my app but I inadvertently created and upload an x64 .appxupload file to the Windows Dev Center for a windows Store App. I wasn't building an x64 version because there is no x64 version of SQLite. I renamed an x86 file to the x64 file name and uploaded that so that the x64 file contains an x86 version, but that might cause me trouble somehow.

So how do I delete the x64 app package that I don't want? The phone Dev Center has a Delete option, but the Windows Dev Center for Windows app doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacting Microsoft support was the only way to get this done.

Comment: The MS support team confirmed this.

Answer (score 1):

In the package area, following this path: Submissions -> "Submission xy" -> Packages -> Show Details you will find the Remove-Button.

At least this is how it is now [20151010]. I was also searching in google where to find it... ;)

After you have clicked it, it changes to Revert.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update the submission 
expand packages
select remove on the package to remove
Click save.
Click Submit to the Store.
This created a new submission.
What a confusing interface!